# Show counsel-ag results in separate buffer?

Tags: projectile, ivy, counsel, swiper

I use `counsel-projectile` for Ivy + Projectile interoperability.

But, when I run something like `C-c p s s` / `M-x counsel-projectile-ag`, the results are shown in the minibuffer, and I can't see any obvious way to move them to a buffer.

Is there a way to show these output in a buffer, rather than the Ivy minibuffer? Is it possible to return to a previous Ivy session? Is there a best-practices way to rebind the key to the original `projectile-ag` behavior?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `C-c C-o` (`ivy-occur`) in the minibuffer.